# JavaFX two dimensional ObservableList

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

How can i use two dimensional ObservableList in JavaFX? Or maybe use ObservableList with array of something, like

```
ObservableList<MyObject[]>
```

Maybe you can help me here? Anything simpler, is it two dimensional ObservableList or ObservableList with arrat or even other solution if exist.
i tried with FXCollections method but nothing fit with this case.
Anybody can help me here?

Comment: What is your use case? How are you going to bind or observe that ObservableList of ObservableLists to JavaFX controls? Maybe ArrayList of ObservableLists is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't clearly understand, what you want to reach, using 2 dimensional data structure :

if you want a matrix with observing of items modification create arrayList of ObservaleArrayLists,

if you want a comb data structure - use observable list of observable lists.

But JavaFX doesn't support any 2-dimensional data structures, and seems, will not support. JavaFX will provide basic data structures. And you can use them to build anything you want.

It looks like matrix 10x10:

```
    ObservableList<ObservableList<Integer>> matrix = FXCollections.<ObservableList<Integer>>observableArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final ObservableList<Integer> row = FXCollections.<Integer>observableArrayList();
        matrix.add(i, row);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            row.add(0);
        }
    }
```